# Using if and if else in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom-events

I have some function to validate some input field like this:

```
function validateName() {
        var inputName = document.getElementById('name');
        var pesanError ='';
        if (inputName.value ===""){
            pesanError = 'Name can't be empty'
            tambahError('name',pesanError)
        }else if(inputName.value !="" && inputName.value.length < 3){
            remove('name');
            pesanError = 'Name is too short'
            tambahError('name',pesanError)
        }else{
            remove('name')
        }
    }
```

and I use add event like this:

```
var inputName = document.getElementById('name');
inputName.addEventListener("blur", validateName, true);
```

Well it works fine, when it empty it display "name can't be empty" and when have value but has a length less than 3 it will display "name is too short", but the problem is after it has value and display "name is too short" and then the field have no value again it still display "name is too short". So my question how can I can make my function so it will display "name can't be empty" again when the value turn back into no value again.

Here's remove function and tambahError function:

```
function remove(id) {
        var element = id + "Error";
        var inputName = document.getElementById(element);
        if (inputName !== undefined){
            inputName.remove();
        }
    }
function tambahError(kolom,pesan) {
        if (document.getElementById(kolom+"Error")== undefined){
            var inputName = document.getElementById(kolom);
            var h = document.createElement("span");
            h.id = kolom+"Error";
            var t = document.createTextNode(pesan);
            h.appendChild(t);
            h.className='error';
            insertAfter(h, inputName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is the name too short when less than 3? I know a lot of people with 2 letter names

Comment: We have no idea what your `tambahError` function does - could be that it just _appends_ error messages to the target element, instead of replacing them.

Comment: could you post the `remove` and `tambahError` functions code ! that may help

Comment: @Ayaou done, i already add it here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
pesanError = 'Name can't be empty'
```

change the string to

```
pesanError = 'Name can\'t be empty'
```

this should fix the error

Answer (score 0):

> We have no idea what your tambahError and pesanError and remove do.

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <script>
function validateName() {
        var inputName = document.getElementById('name');
        var pesanError ='';
        if (inputName.value ===""){
            alert("Name can't be empty");
        }else if(inputName.value !="" && inputName.value.length < 3){
            alert("Name is short");
        }else{
            alert("remove name");
        }
    }

  var inputName = document.getElementById('name');
inputName.addEventListener("blur", validateName, true);

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='name'></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I already update my question with tambahError and pesanError function in it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find my own answer, The problem is createTextNode can't be updated, so i just remove the span and create new node again like this:

```
function validateName() {
        var inputName = document.getElementById('name');
        var pesanError ='';
        if (inputName.value ===""){
            remove('name');
            pesanError = 'Nama tidak boleh kosong';
            tambahError('name',pesanError)
        }else if(inputName.value !="" && inputName.value.length < 3){
            remove('name');
            pesanError = 'Nama yang anda masukkan terlalu pendek'
            tambahError('name',pesanError)
        }else{
            remove('name')
        }
    }
```